# How to get date localisation working on Google Firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, localization, google-cloud-functions, momentjs

I'm running an application based on the Google Firebase platform, using multiple cloud functions. Everything is working fine but I just cannot get date localisation working.
I made a test function (see below) where I tried everything I could think of to see how I could get a correctly formatted date out of the platform, but nothing worked.

The date just keeps getting formatted and offset to UTC I believe (see the response below).

Is there something I am overlooking? Are there any other suggestions I could try?

I have deployed the function in "europe-west1" (which should actually already BE in the timezone I want... :D) using the Node.js 10 (beta) runner. (I also ran the function in Node.js 8 with the same result)
My dependencies are the following versions as of writing:

```
    "date-fns": "^2.11.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
```

If someone could shine a light on this, that would be AMAZING!

```
import moment from "moment";
import "moment/locale/nl-be";
import { format, parseISO } from "date-fns";
import nl from "date-fns/locale/nl";

moment.locale("nl-be");

exports.test = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const input = "2020-02-04T15:00:00+01:00";
    const now = new Date();

    return res.status(200).send({
      expectedResult: "04/02/2020 15:00",
      locales: moment.locales(),
      locale: moment.locale(),
      original: input,
      formatted: moment(input).format(),
      basic: moment(input).format("L HH:mm"),
      utc: moment.utc(input).format("L HH:mm"),
      basicLocal: moment(input).local().format("L HH:mm"),
      utcLocal: moment.utc(input).local().format("L HH:mm"),
      forcedLocale: moment(input).locale("nl-be").format("L HH:mm"),
      utcForcedLocale: moment.utc(input).locale("nl-be").format("L HH:mm"),
      parsedDate: parseISO(input),
      dateFnsNoLocal: format(parseISO(input), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),
      dateFns: format(parseISO(input), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", {
        locale: nl,
      }),
      now: now.toLocaleString("nl-BE"),
      nowMoment: moment(now).format(),
      nowMomentFormat: moment(now).format("L HH:mm"),
    });
  });
```

response:

```
{
   "expectedResult": "04/02/2020 15:00",
   "locales": [
      "en",
      "nl-be"
   ],
   "locale": "nl-be",
   "original": "2020-02-04T15:00:00+01:00",
   "formatted": "2020-02-04T14:00:00+00:00",
   "basic": "04/02/2020 14:00",
   "utc": "04/02/2020 14:00",
   "basicLocal": "04/02/2020 14:00",
   "utcLocal": "04/02/2020 14:00",
   "forcedLocale": "04/02/2020 14:00",
   "utcForcedLocale": "04/02/2020 14:00",
   "parsedDate": "2020-02-04T14:00:00.000Z",
   "dateFnsNoLocal": "04/02/2020 14:00",
   "dateFns": "04/02/2020 14:00",
   "now": "4/17/2020, 1:55:52 PM",
   "nowMoment": "2020-04-17T13:55:52+00:00",
   "nowMomentFormat": "17/04/2020 13:55"
}
```

Code gives me correct results when I run it in for example a code sandebox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-germain-b1vty?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to solve my issue and that was by using the `moment-timezone` library. Forcing it to convert to a specific timezone and then formatting the date.

Comment: Changing the library used is not a solution. Moreover moment js developers heavily discourage using their library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to localize and format dates with `date-fns`,
I recommend using [date-fns-tz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz).

You can solve this in many ways, but try not to use `moment` and `moment-tz` since, according to [their doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

> We now generally consider Moment to be a legacy project in maintenance mode. It is not dead, but it is indeed done.